# SharePoint Configuration Wizard Error. Feature With ID "Feature GUID" Failed validation. file BasicWebparts/feature.xml

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, image, configuration-wizard, microsoft

I am Getting below error while running the SharePoint product configuration wizard.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

[image]

Comment: check if this helps: https://github.com/dsccommunity/SharePointDsc/issues/982

Comment: No its not helpful. It is asking to delete a full fledge SDK. is it a best practice to delete a SDK which can create problem for other SDK as well?

Answer (score 0):

For resolve this issue needs small analyze for orchard and breaking dependency before update use powershell scripts. For this issue in one feature where contains this web part not defined required attribute. You can try fix in your project where this web part and feature defined. If project has been lost you can try import wsp from farm and fix inside in wsp this feature.xml. If all methods not fixed this you can try analyze this feature in HIVE locally where farm store all feature and check manually this feature.xml for errors.